# Filemaker: display related records based on date

Tags: filemaker

I have 3 tables,
Table 1:
Client
Table 2:
Followups
Table 3:
Referrals

It's a one to many relationship where one client can have multiple followup or referrals.

How do I display the Followups and Referrals between 2 dates?
I have a summary field which counts the total of each followup and referrals but they show me all the count rather than in between a given date

Answer (score 1):

In your relationship graph make a new table occurance that restricts the related set based on a date range. Here is an example image. You can make "date one" and "date two" globals so that they are not stored, and operate across all records. Base your sum / count calcuations based on this relationship.
[image: Relationship Graph]

Otherwise you can use a sub-summary on your layout in list view, and place the Summary fields in the sub summary. The summary field will show the sum for that sub section.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to place the summary field inside a one-row portal and filter the portal to show only records within the desired range.

This requires much less resources than adding filtered relationships - but it can be slow if you have too many related records.